# Quero salvar em um novo arquivo txt uma cópia de outro txt em Python

Tags: python

```
arq = open("/Users/DIGITAL/Desktop/Python/novo.txt", "w")
arq.write(palavras)
arq.close()
```

Estou usando esse código, mas ele só aceita string.

Comment: Pode detalhar melhor o que quer fazer? O que é `palavras`? Qual é o outro arquivo? Você quer copiar um arquivo inteiro para outro? Se sim, por quê não apenas copiar o arquivo ao invés de ler um e escrever em outro?

Comment: Palavras é o que estou usando pra salvar essa nova ordenação. Eu quero salvar no arquivo novo a ordenação depois de aplicar o quicksort


with open('/Users/DIGITAL/Desktop/Python/teste.txt') as f:
    palavras = Counter( f.read().split())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo desse tipo:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as arquivo_existente, open('novo_arquivo.txt', 
'w') as novo_arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo_existente.readlines():
        novo_arquivo.write(linha)
```

Ao executar o código acima, o conteúdo do `arquivo_existente.txt` será copiado para o arquivo `novo_arquivo.txt`

Comment: Dica: você pode, a partir da versão 2.7, utilizar as duas expressões `with` numa mesma só: `with open(...) as a1, open(...) as a2`, e ler o conteúdo inteiro com `read()` ao invés de linha a linha com `readlines()`.